# Unabe to Update File Name in php and MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an update form with 3 input fields. The input type is file and user can upload and update existing file to a new file. May I know why does only 1 input field is able to upload and update the file name on db. The other two input fields are unable to update the name of the file in db. Here is the codes for references;

**html**

```
<form class="pr_form" name="pr" method="post" action="updated-form.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="uploaded[]" class="filestyle" data-buttonText="Update Quotation 1" multiple="multiple"> //only this field can update the file name on db
<input type="file" name="uploaded[]" class="filestyle" data-buttonText="Update Quotation 1" multiple="multiple">
<input type="file" name="uploaded[]" class="filestyle" data-buttonText="Update Quotation 1" multiple="multiple">
</form>
```

**php & MySQL**

```
//validation and $_POST code here 
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['uploaded']['name']); $i++) {
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'][$i];
    if($tmpFilePath != "" || !empty($tmpFilePath)) {
        $shortname = $_FILES['uploaded']['name'][$i];
        $filePath = "uploads/" . date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['uploaded']['name'][$i];
        if(!$msgError && move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $filePath)) {
            $sql = "UPDATE purchase SET quotation_1='".date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['uploaded']['name'][0]."',quotation_2='".date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['uploaded']['name'][1]."',quotation_3='".date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['uploaded']['name'][2]."' WHERE pr_id='$pr_id'";
        }
    }
}
//query and success/fail message
```

The Files was uploaded successfully on the folder but on the db, the file name is empty for input field no 2 & 3. For example, if user want to upload/update only field no 2, user need to use field no 1 to upload the file. Thanks in advance for the help. Do advice me if I have any error on the codes

> **Edited Codes**

sorry for my mistake for making others confuse. Hope this helps:

```
if(isset($_FILES['uploaded'])){
        //select file name on db to check whether file exist or not 
        $sql="SELECT * FROM purchase WHERE pr_id='$pr_id'";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $quotation_1=$row['quotation_1'];
                $quotation_2=$row['quotation_2'];
                $quotation_3=$row['quotation_3'];
            }
        }
        for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['uploaded']['name']); $i++){
            $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'][$i];
            if($tmpFilePath != "" || !empty($tmpFilePath)){
                $shortname = $_FILES['uploaded']['name'][$i];
                $filePath = "uploads/" . date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['uploaded']['name'][$i];
            //}
        if(!$msgError){
            if($quotation_1!=NULL && $quotation_2!=NULL && $quotation_3==NULL){
                $sql = "UPDATE purchase SET quotation_3='".date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['uploaded']['name'][0]."' WHERE pr_id='$pr_id'";
            } elseif($quotation_1!=NULL && $quotation_2==NULL && $quotation_3!=NULL){
                $sql = "UPDATE purchase SET quotation_2='".date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['uploaded']['name'][0]."' WHERE pr_id='$pr_id'";
            } elseif($quotation_1==NULL && $quotation_2!=NULL && $quotation_3!=NULL){
                $sql = "UPDATE purchase SET quotation_1='".date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['uploaded']['name'][0]."' WHERE pr_id='$pr_id'";
            } elseif($quotation_1!=NULL && $quotation_2==NULL && $quotation_3==NULL){
                $sql = "UPDATE purchase SET quotation_2='".date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['uploaded']['name'][0]."',quotation_3='".date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['uploaded']['name'][1]."' WHERE pr_id='$pr_id'";
            } elseif($quotation_1==NULL && $quotation_2==NULL && $quotation_3==NULL){
                $sql = "UPDATE purchase SET quotation_1='".date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['uploaded']['name'][0]."',quotation_2='".date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['uploaded']['name'][1]."',quotation_3='".date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['uploaded']['name'][2]."' WHERE pr_id='$pr_id'";
            } elseif($quotation_1==NULL && $quotation_2!=NULL && $quotation_3==NULL){
                $sql = "UPDATE purchase SET quotation_1='".date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['uploaded']['name'][0]."',quotation_3='".date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['uploaded']['name'][1]."' WHERE pr_id='$pr_id'";
            } elseif($quotation_1==NULL && $quotation_2==NULL && $quotation_3!=NULL){
                $sql = "UPDATE purchase SET quotation_1='".date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['uploaded']['name'][0]."',quotation_2='".date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['uploaded']['name'][1]."' WHERE pr_id='$pr_id'";
            }
        }
       }
}
//query and success/fail msg
```

Comment: you work in a loop with each file but in your query work with all files? I recommend you re-think what you really want to do.

Comment: Why would you include 3 upload names in your SQL query when looping through the different uploads?  I can't understand how you intend to organize things here, which is probably related to your issue.

Comment: sorry but this Update code is ugliest code i've seen today :) You are a programator not a copy/paste machine. Add more dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `UPDATE` query is updating all 3 `quotation_X` columns, even if the user only uploaded one file. So all the other columns get blank names. You should just update the column corresponding to the file that was uploaded.

```
$sql = "UPDATE purchase SET quotation_" . ($i+1) . " = '" . date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['uploaded']['name'][$i]."' WHERE pr_id='$pr_id'";
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. will try it

Comment: it does working but it's only able to upload update 1 file only. If I want to update more than 1 file, I have to re-upload again for the 2nd file. Thanks

Comment: @Amran how can it be possible if sql update query is modified to the file with which oprerates?

Comment: Managed to do it. The problem is actually the name of the file to upload. Example, if I upload field number 2, then, it should be `$_FILES['uploaded']['name'][1]` or field no 3, `$_FILES['uploaded']['name'][2]`. Many thanks for the help& advice guys. Will improve more on my programming skills.

Comment: @Amran It should take all the files because of the `for()` loop. That's why I have `($i + 1)` in the query. When `$i` is `1`, it puts the filename in `quotation_2`.

Answer (score 1):

try edit your query like this

```
    for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['uploaded']['name']); $i++) {
        $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'][$i];
        if($tmpFilePath != "" || !empty($tmpFilePath)) {
            $shortname = $_FILES['uploaded']['name'][$i];
            $filePath = "uploads/" . date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['uploaded']['name'][$i];
            if(!$msgError && move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $filePath)) {
                $fileIndex= $i+1;
                $sql = "UPDATE purchase SET quotation_$fileIndex='".date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['uploaded']['name'][$fileIndex]."' WHERE pr_id='$pr_id'";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will try to write to `quotation_0` column. You need to add 1 to `$i` to get the number for the database column.

Comment: @Barmar I saw it after post. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the help. will try it

Comment: Your correction of `$i= $i+1;` has an undesired side-effect on the loop.  You should use a different variable for simplicity.